# set "LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS = true" to remove --no-undefined from the linker flags

Tags: android, undefined, undefined-symbol

in Android.mk i set "LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS = true", but in the result, " -Wl,--no-undefined "still shows up. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue until I moved the line at the very top of my Android.mk (even above `LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)`)